# Run php file in background

Tags: php

I have a php file that allows me to add news to my website, I have also a crontab that runs every morning, this file checks if there is any news that isn't sent to subscribers and sends it to 600~ emails.

What I want to do is after I insert the news it should also be sent to all those ~600 emails, that means i have to fire that file somehow in the background after I press the "Publish News" button.

I have to fire it in the background because it will take about 1hr to send all those e-mails.

Any ideas how can I fire it in the background ?

Comment: 1 hour to send 600 emails? May be you start to optimize this code.

Comment: For background processes you need to start considering messaging queues that can run code detached from current session. One I have tried and find to be effective is RabbitMQ. I think its worth looking at messaging systems for tasks like this. https://www.rabbitmq.com/features.html

Comment: @AlBundy The code is optimized. there is just a little code that selects the e-mails from the database and than i'm using phpmailer for delivering. The idea that it will take that long is that i'm using Gmail to send the e-mails and for that i have to add 5s delay between each email

Answer (score 0):

use shell_exec http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

or
run your cronjob every minute.

Answer (score -1):

Honestly your current approach seems awful, but whatever. I'll work with that.

The easiest way to do this is to just run away from the core issue with the magic of JQuery.

```
<button onclick='$.ajax({url: "/publishnews.php"});'>Publish News</button>
```

This sends an ajax web request to the script that will presumably do everything you need it to do in the background.